# What's wrong with PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher?

Tags: android, phone-number

In my app I'm trying to format the phone number typed in an `EditText`. For that I'm using a [PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html).

I'm having issues with this class. Trying to use the constructor `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(String countryCode)` doesn't compile. I can't find it in the documentation but it's definitely in the sdk (see [the code source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java#L71)).

What's wrong with that class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(String countryCode)` is hidden API, as you can see from the `@hide` tag in the javadoc. In other words: that particular constructor is not part of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you to use `PhoneNumberUtils` to format a phone number.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

And especially these two methods:

- `formatNumber(String source)` Breaks the given number down and formats it according to the rules for the country the number is from.
- `formatNumber(Editable text, int defaultFormattingType)` Formats a phone number in-place.

Comment: the problem with that is that i want to pass the country code to the formatter, PhoneNumberUtils default to the default locale, then looks at the phone country indicator. but in case this is not provided, it's screwed

Comment: You can use `getFormatTypeForLocale(Locale locale)` to get the formatingType and use it into `formatNumber`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, this CTOR is available from API21 , so you can either copy the code for pre-Lollipop, or use it when you can:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html#PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(java.lang.String)